# Mysterious errors from Python BytesIO objects

Tags: python, memory, download

I'm writing a Python preprocessing pipeline for medium-sized data files (roughly 0.5 GB each) which are downloaded from the internet. The preprocessing stage usually discards more than 95% of the data in each file, so it seems wasteful (and slow) to download the raw files to disk before paring them down to a much smaller size. The code I inherited involves copying each raw file into a `BytesIO` object, which provides the same interface as a binary file but holds the contents in RAM. The download looks something like this:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(dataurl)
response.begin()
with BytesIO() as memfile:
   while True:
      chunk = response.read()
      if chunk:
         memfile.write(chunk)
      else:
         break
   preprocess_file(memfile)    # this method saves the useful contents of the file
```

The problem is that running this code causes a `MemoryError` on every tenth file or so. The intermittency of the problem makes it hard to reproduce simply. I'm trying to understand why this occurs, and how to prevent it.

Comment: As an experiment, you could print the size of each chunk and comment out the `preprocess_file`. You could also try `del chunk` and `del response` after the loop, but not expecting much there. "about every 10 times" - is this in some other larger loop or thread?

Comment: Is the memory all being cleared? Like, maybe there are references remaining to the full `memfile` before it's processed. Please try to make a [mre] and include the [full error message with traceback](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341), otherwise we can only guess. To reproduce the issue but avoid having to download files over and over, you might try randomly generating some data (seeded so it's reproducible).

Comment: Are there other threads in the same program doing the same thing and all the memory is adding up. Maybe put a counting semaphore around them so you do no more than 6-8 at a time.